# what is the difference of self.function vs function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Assume I have a class `CLASS` and I create a method`fnc` in it

```py
class CLASS():

   def __init__(self,arg):
         #initizalize
         self.arg = arg
   def fnc(self):
      print(self.arg)
```

if I (in my class) wants to call `fnc` in a method `prnt` I can do it in two different ways, one using `self.fnc` and one just using `fnc`

```py
class CLASS():

   def __init__(self,arg):
         #initizalize
         self.arg = arg
   def fnc(self):
      print(self.arg)

   def prnt(self):
     self.fnc() #Method one
     fnc()      #Method two
```

which both seems to be working. I do know the `self` argument and how it works, but I do not understand the difference of the two method/function calls.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/

Comment: Thank you very much :) I dont understand the downvotes though...

Comment: What you have posted cannot possibly 'work'. But then again you have not shown how you use your `CLASS`, so we can't know.

Comment: That has been corrected now -  but that is not the problem of the question. The code is just an example of the understanding the question (difference of the two function calls)

Comment: Even after correcting your code from `print(arg)` to `print(self.arg)`, you are still left with `self.fnc()` and `fnc()` in your second sample. Again `fnc()` does not exist in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

This should not work. It works because `CLASS` in your code is not actually a class since you used keyword `def` instead of `class` to define it.

What you actually did is define a function `CLASS`, which when executed defines some other functions.

To correct this declare your class like this:

```
class CLASS:
```

And your second call will raise a `NameError` probably because `fnc` does not exist in the scope of your method.

Comment: That is edited now - in my code I have used the "class" object and not "def" (brain fart from my part, when I wrote the problem here). Thanks for noticing :) 

It seems like prashant has answered the question though (static vs. method) in the link he provided

Comment: Even with the correct keyword, sample code will not work. It might accept your class as a valid one, but running `fnc` method will not work because `arg` does not exist in the scope of the method, you need `print(self.arg)` for it to work.

Comment: That has been corrected now -  but that is not the problem of the question. The code is just an example of the understanding the question (difference of the two function calls). But thanks

Comment: Your example does not work though, 100% raises a `NameError`.